# PHP Lithium - performance with or without model scheme definition mysql only

Tags: php, lithium

In model class, it provide a way to define the db table scheme manually. I didn't use it when I design the model class for mysql db adapter, and it's working well. I think Lithium will retrive the scheme information from mysql db automatically, so I have some performance concern, is it better performance if I use "scheme definition" in model class? Should I always use "scheme definition" in model class?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice is to use a filter to cache the schema in production, like this: http://www.komposta.net/article/lithium-model-schema-caching